# UIPushEffect not having desired "up flick" effect

Tags: ios

I want this item to Pop up briefly before being pulled down by gravity. Right now if I add the push effect it launches down.

```
//Animate this new fake button
    UIGravityBehavior* gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[fakeButton]];
    [gravity setMagnitude:1.0f];

    UIPushBehavior *upFlick = [[UIPushBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[fakeButton] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
    [upFlick setAngle:M_PI/3 magnitude:1.0f];
    [self.animator addBehavior:gravity];
    [self.animator addBehavior:upFlick];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make either the angle or the magnitude negative, and that should make it go up (and to the side). If you want it to go straight up, you should also change the angle to M_PI/2.